# Debugging with find_all()[]

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, findall

I have to debug code that I haven't written. I think I found the problem in this line, but it is not clear to me what it does. Can anyone explain it to me?

```
 number_of_items_found = int(soup.find_all('li')[3].text.split(' ')[0])
```

Comment: looks like a scraper. Gets text from the 4th "li" element in soup, then takes the text up to the first space and converts it to an int.

Comment: Thanks, it wasn't clear to me the '3'! Now i got it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are using BeautifulSoup to scrape an html text.
So the `soup.find_all('li')` part will extract every `<li>..</li>` tag from your html.
Then you access the fourth of those tags (index = 3) and split its text at spaces.

For example: If the text that the `li` contains is something like `12 books in your cart` then using `.split(' ')` on it will give you a list: `['12', 'books', 'in', 'your', 'cart']`.

After you access the first element of the list (index = 0) and convert it to an integer. So to continue with the assumed text and list above the outcome will be: `int('12') -> 12`.

Hope it makes sense.